# How to pass xml as a parameter in python script?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, urllib2

I have the parameters to be passed to my python code saved in an xml file. 
How to pass this xml as a parameter to my python code?
Can someone please help on this?

Thanks in Adavce!

Comment: You can simply pass the path to XML file and parse that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a command line parameter when executing the script. Use [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), the array that stores all the arguments passed or [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module, that handles customisable command line parameters

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have "file.xml" as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <address>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <position>CEO</position>
    </address>
```

You can either:

- Pass the XML file as a command line parameter to your python script.

  Usage: script.py path/to/file.xml

  ```
  import sys
  from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

  def read_xml(xml_file):
          with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
                  data = f.read()

          return parseString(data)

  if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
          print "Error: Missing parameter."
  else:
          dom = read_xml(sys.argv[1])
          tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].toxml()

          print tag
  ```

  It will be better if you use argparse module instead of sys.argv.
- Or just open and read the XML file and parse it.

  ```
  from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

  def read_xml(xml_file):
          with open(xml_file, 'r') as f:
                  data = f.read()

          return parseString(data)

  dom = read_xml("file.xml")
  tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].toxml()

  print tag
  ```

Comment: `def read_xml("path/to/file.xml"):` .. that is a very strange `def`. I think you were thinking about calling it while you wrote that.